# EasySlider1.7 - How Do I Get Arrows on a Second Slider To Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, easyslider

I figured out how to have 2 sliders on the page from other posts. 
The only final issue I have is that the Prev & Next arrows on the second slider don't seem to function.

I took this page over from someone else that originally build the first slider and am not very versed with code at all. I've been using mostly Wordpress for years. Learning as I go.

Here is the page:
[GinaKetchum.com](http://ginaketchum.com)

The code in the index.html file:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easySlider1.7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#slider").easySlider({
    auto: true, 
    continuous: true
   });
   $("#slider2").easySlider({
    auto: true, 
    continuous: true
   });
  }); 
 </script>
```

The code in easySlider1.7.js:

```js
(function($) {

 $.fn.easySlider = function(options){
   
  // default configuration properties
  var defaults = {   
   prevId:   'prevBtn',
   prevText:   'Previous',
   nextId:   'nextBtn', 
   nextText:   'Next',
   controlsShow: true,
   controlsBefore: '',
   controlsAfter: '', 
   controlsFade: true,
   firstId:   'firstBtn',
   firstText:   'First',
   firstShow:  false,
   lastId:   'lastBtn', 
   lastText:   'Last',
   lastShow:  false,    
   vertical:  false,
   speed:    500,
   auto:   false,
   pause:   5000,
   continuous:  false, 
   numeric:   false,
   numericId:   'controls'
  }; 
  
  var options = $.extend(defaults, options);  
    
  this.each(function() {  
   var obj = $(this);     
   var s = $("li", obj).length;
   var w = $("li", obj).width(); 
   var h = $("li", obj).height(); 
   var clickable = true;
   obj.width(w); 
   obj.height(h); 
   obj.css("overflow","hidden");
   var ts = s-1;
   var t = 0;
   $("ul", obj).css('width',s*w);   
   
   if(options.continuous){
    $("ul", obj).prepend($("ul li:last-child", obj).clone().css("margin-left","-"+ w +"px"));
    $("ul", obj).append($("ul li:nth-child(2)", obj).clone());
    $("ul", obj).css('width',(s+1)*w);
   };    
   
   if(!options.vertical) $("li", obj).css('float','left');
        
   if(options.controlsShow){
    var html = options.controlsBefore;    
    if(options.numeric){
     html += '<ol id="'+ options.numericId +'"></ol>';
    } else {
     if(options.firstShow) html += '<span id="'+ options.firstId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.firstText +'</a></span>';
     html += ' <span id="'+ options.prevId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.prevText +'</a></span>';
     html += ' <span id="'+ options.nextId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.nextText +'</a></span>';
     if(options.lastShow) html += ' <span id="'+ options.lastId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.lastText +'</a></span>';    
    };
    
    html += options.controlsAfter;      
    $(obj).after(html);          
   };
   
   if(options.numeric){         
    for(var i=0;i<s;i++){      
     $(document.createElement("li"))
      .attr('id',options.numericId + (i+1))
      .html('<a rel='+ i +' href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ (i+1) +'</a>')
      .appendTo($("#"+ options.numericId))
      .click(function(){       
       animate($("a",$(this)).attr('rel'),true);
      });             
    };       
   } else {
    $("a","#"+options.nextId).click(function(){  
     animate("next",true);
    });
    $("a","#"+options.prevId).click(function(){  
     animate("prev",true);    
    }); 
    $("a","#"+options.firstId).click(function(){  
     animate("first",true);
    });    
    $("a","#"+options.lastId).click(function(){  
     animate("last",true);    
    });    
   };
   
   function setCurrent(i){
    i = parseInt(i)+1;
    $("li", "#" + options.numericId).removeClass("current");
    $("li#" + options.numericId + i).addClass("current");
   };
   
   function adjust(){
    if(t>ts) t=0;  
    if(t<0) t=ts; 
    if(!options.vertical) {
     $("ul",obj).css("margin-left",(t*w*-1));
    } else {
     $("ul",obj).css("margin-left",(t*h*-1));
    }
    clickable = true;
    if(options.numeric) setCurrent(t);
   };
   
   function animate(dir,clicked){
    if (clickable){
     clickable = false;
     var ot = t;    
     switch(dir){
      case "next":
       t = (ot>=ts) ? (options.continuous ? t+1 : ts) : t+1;      
       break; 
      case "prev":
       t = (t<=0) ? (options.continuous ? t-1 : 0) : t-1;
       break; 
      case "first":
       t = 0;
       break; 
      case "last":
       t = ts;
       break; 
      default:
       t = dir;
       break; 
     }; 
     var diff = Math.abs(ot-t);
     var speed = diff*options.speed;      
     if(!options.vertical) {
      p = (t*w*-1);
      $("ul",obj).animate(
       { marginLeft: p }, 
       { queue:false, duration:speed, complete:adjust }
      );    
     } else {
      p = (t*h*-1);
      $("ul",obj).animate(
       { marginTop: p }, 
       { queue:false, duration:speed, complete:adjust }
      );     
     };
     
     if(!options.continuous && options.controlsFade){     
      if(t==ts){
       $("a","#"+options.nextId).hide();
       $("a","#"+options.lastId).hide();
      } else {
       $("a","#"+options.nextId).show();
       $("a","#"+options.lastId).show();     
      };
      if(t==0){
       $("a","#"+options.prevId).hide();
       $("a","#"+options.firstId).hide();
      } else {
       $("a","#"+options.prevId).show();
       $("a","#"+options.firstId).show();
      };     
     };    
     
     if(clicked) clearTimeout(timeout);
     if(options.auto && dir=="next" && !clicked){;
      timeout = setTimeout(function(){
       animate("next",false);
      },diff*options.speed+options.pause);
     };
   
    };
    
   };
   // init
   var timeout;
   if(options.auto){;
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
     animate("next",false);
    },options.pause);
   };  
   
   if(options.numeric) setCurrent(0);
  
   if(!options.continuous && options.controlsFade){     
    $("a","#"+options.prevId).hide();
    $("a","#"+options.firstId).hide();    
   };    
   
  });
   
 };

})(jQuery);
```

The css file:

```css
/*Slider*/   

.graphic, #prevBtn, #nextBtn, #slider1prev, #slider1next {
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:block;
overflow:hidden;
text-indent:-8000px;
}
   
.container-slider{
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
text-align:left;
width:900px;
background:#fff;
}

#slider ul, #slider li,
#slider2 ul, #slider2 li{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}

#slider2{margin-top:1em;}

#slider li, #slider2 li{ 
width:900px;
height:396px;
overflow:hidden;
} 

#prevBtn, #nextBtn,
#slider1next, #slider1prev{
display:block;
width:30px;
height:77px;
position:absolute;
left:-35px;
top:160px;
z-index:1000;
}
 
#nextBtn, #slider1next{
left:905px;
}
              
#prevBtn a, #nextBtn a,
#slider1next a, #slider1prev a{
display:block;
position:relative;
width:29px;
height:51px;
background-image: url(../images/btn_prev2.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0 0;
}
 
#nextBtn a, #slider1next a{
background-image: url(../images/btn_next2.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0 0;
}  

ol#controls{
margin:1em 0;
padding:0;
height:28px; 
}

ol#controls li{
margin:0 10px 0 0; 
padding:0;
float:left;
list-style:none;
height:28px;
line-height:28px;
}

ol#controls li a{
float:left;
height:28px;
line-height:28px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
background:#DAF3F8;
color:#555;
padding:0 10px;
text-decoration:none;
}
  
ol#controls li.current a{
background:#5DC9E1;
color:#fff;
}

ol#controls li a:focus, #prevBtn a:focus, #nextBtn a:focus{outline:none;}
 
/*Slider*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the id of the prev/next buttons for the second slider, then do something like:

```
$("#slider2").easySlider({
    auto: true,
    continuous: true,
    nextId: "slider1next",
    prevId: "slider1prev"
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have worked! I ended up with this: ` $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#slider").easySlider({
    auto: true, 
    continuous: true,
    prevId: 'prevBtn',
                nextId: 'nextBtn'
   });
   $("#slider2").easySlider({
    auto: true, 
    continuous: true,
                nextId: "slider1next",
          prevId: "slider1prev"
   });
  });  `

Answer (score 0):

This change seems to have worked.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#slider").easySlider({
    auto: true, 
    continuous: true,
    prevId: 'prevBtn',
                nextId: 'nextBtn'
   });
   $("#slider2").easySlider({
    auto: true, 
    continuous: true,
                nextId: "slider1next",
          prevId: "slider1prev"
   });
  });
```